# I have 3 different distros in use and I want to refer 3 Transmissions to one config file?

Tags: directory, transmission

On my machine, 3 different Linux distributions are installed: Ubuntu + Magiea Gnome + Manjaro KDE

I use a torrent client (called Transmission) within them. So I want to use one config directory for all of these Transmisions.

Now, those 3 Transmissions use 3 different directories:

```
/home/ubuntu-user/.config/transmission
/home/magiea-user/.config/transmission
/home/manjaro-user/.config/transmission
```

I want to force the 2 else ones to use this directory as config-directory: `/home/ubuntu-user/.config/transmission`

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration settings for `transmission-daemon` are specified via `CONFIG_DIR="/home/${USER}/.config/transmission-daemon"` in `/etc/default/transmission-daemon`.

You might want to change these settings in the other two installations on your pc.

Comment: On Ubuntu, It's this: `CONFIG_DIR="/var/lib/transmission-daemon/info"` And in the other 2 /etc/default directories there is not any transmisstion-daemon file while Transmission-gtk is installed in both distros